# Does 2SAT contained in SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, satisfiability

Is it true that $2 S A T \subseteq S A T ?$ and in general is $k S A T \subseteq S A T $ where k is any positive integer is true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The definition for SAT is: $SAT:=\{\varphi\in\Sigma^*|\varphi\text{ is a logic formula, and }\exists a.\varphi(a)=True\}$

The definition for kSAT is: $kSAT:=\{\varphi\in\Sigma^*|\varphi\text{ is a 2CNF logic formula (its just a specific form) and }\exists a.\varphi(a)=True\}$

As you can see, from the definition we would have $kSAT\subseteq SAT$.

***It's important to note*** that the 2SAT problem is **known to be easy** (aka is in $P$), although SAT is **not known to be easy, but is known to be $NP-Complete$**.

In addition, for every $k\ge 3$, we have $kSAT$ is $NP-Complete$